# Load elisp file only when file with specific extension is opened

Tags: init-file, slime

I've been using SLIME mode with the [quicklisp slime helper](https://github.com/quicklisp/quicklisp-slime-helper), and I load the package with the following code (in my `.emacs`):

```
(load (expand-file-name slime-helper-path))
(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")
(require 'slime-autoloads)
```

However, I noticed that the `load` uses a lot of startup time. I'd like to only call that code when I open a lisp file (and not on startup), or when I call the `slime` function. How could I do that ?

Comment: Check out [`autoload`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Autoload.html).

Comment: Not too clear (to me). You seem to be saying that (1) you want to use slime **before** you visit any Lisp file, (2) you cannot use slime without **first loading** the helper file, and (3) you don't want to load the helper file **until you visit a Lisp file**. That's sounds logically impossible. Please try to clarify the problem/question.

Comment: @Drew Sorry my question is indeed quite unclear. I only meant (2) and (3). However, Dan's solution with using autoload solves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Dan for suggesting to use `autoload`.

Instead of detecting the file type, I binded the load to the `slime` function, like this:

```
(autoload 'slime "path/to/slime-helper.el "Launch SLIME" t nil)
```

> Evaluating this expression tells Emacs to automatically load the
>   library `slime-helper.el` from load-path, when `slime` is called for the
>   first time—either from Lisp, or interactively with `M-x slime`.

(modified [source](https://www.lunaryorn.com/posts/autoloads-in-emacs-lisp))